# Edx Developer Stack error with Vagrant and Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a problem in running an instance of edX Platform on my PC. I have followed the intsrunctions which are listed here: 
https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack 
 I have installed Vagrant 1.7.2 and Oracle VM VirtualBox 4.3.20. However, when I run the command vagrant up I get this error in the command prompt:

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details:
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
I pasted the full log here:
 http://pastebin.com/PpbnaeSi
I can't figure a solution. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I found an answer. I typed in the command prompt while being at the directory C:\devstack the following:
**vagrant plugin install ffi** and then
**vagrant plugin uninstall ffi** and then
**vagrant plugin install ffi --plugin-version 1.9.8**
Now the devstack box started downloading after typing vagrant up.
Credits to the user who answered this issue: 
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5869